# Render overwritten issue

Tags: rendering

Render overwritten issue 
Hi 
i do render in png pictures and later render in image sequence to get a video. 
somehow an error occurred and i overwrote on my previous renders which took me days to render .
i have gone through a lot of  blender render issues on youtube i can't seem to find one with similar case .
please does anyone have an idea of how i can recover them.
i hope i was clear enough . i can try to explain better if needed. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You must have a path for every different kind of render:

A folder for the image sequence.

A folder for the composites.

And the final render (probably .mp4 or .mov) anywhere.

It's not good to render different renders at the same location because it will be overwritten if the file extension were the same. Eg: png.

Last thing: You cannot recover overwritten files.

[image]